# arrayList swap a number?

Tags: java

I am following some pseudo code, I am currently stuck on this part:
Input: A list (permutation) of size N

1) Let i=j=0

2) While i=j

3)    Let i = UI(1,|T|)

4)    Let j = UI(1,|T|)

5) End While

6) Let temp = ti, Let ti = tj, Let tj = temp

Output: Changed list T

```
static ArrayList<Integer> newSmallChange(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i == j){
        i = CS2004.UI(1, list.size());
        j = CS2004.UI(1, list.size());
    }
    int temp = list.get(i);
}
```

This is the code that i've developed thus far, I am literally just stuck on step 6 as i am unsure how to write that part out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int temp = list.get(i); 
list.set(i, list.get(j)); 
list.set(j, temp);
```